# How to rebalance a passive portfolio if I speculate a war is coming?

Tags: portfolio, rebalancing

Is there a theory about what typically happens to **some** markets when a country goes to war? If yes, should a passive portfolio be rebalanced accordingly? For example [industrial metals](http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/commodities/futures/metals).

Comment: You can invest in military suppliers... Whether you should is something you have to decide for yourself.

Comment: Best to invest in companies that don't have their assets physically within an enemy country. Oh, and try and guess which ones wont have their assets bombed to oblivion.

Answer (score 5):

At a risk of stating the obvious: a passive portfolio doesn't try to speculate on such matters.

Comment: That's what I was also thinking, but historically it sometimes takes decade(s) to recover, which is within the resolution of passive investing,

Answer (score 1):

Normally, in a war everybody suffers and the entire economy goes down. Military contractors do better than average, but the average sucks. The way to take advantage of knowing a war is coming is to leave as soon as possible.

There are strategic materials that can become valuable in a war, but such investments are generally very specialized and not something an ordinary investor would be in a position to exploit.

The most profitable businesses in war are food, oil, and ammunition.